# i think that the code is the same but i don't know why it make different results

Tags: javascript

Why does the code make difference output and it is almost the same input?
Input:

```js
var Add = document.getElementById('AddElement'); //the button
var Element = document.getElementById('element'); // the input text
var ListParent = document.querySelector('ul');
    
Add.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var AddText = document.createElement('li').appendChild(document.createTextNode("hello"));
    ListParent.appendChild(AddText);
})
```

Output:

first click:
hello

second click:
hellohello

```
Input:
```

```js
var Add = document.getElementById('AddElement');
var Element = document.getElementById('element');
var ListParent = document.querySelector('ul');
    
Add.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var AddText = document.createElement('li');
    AddText.appendChild(document.createTextNode('hello'));   
    ListParent.appendChild(AddText);
})
```

Output:
first click:

- hello

second click:

- hello
- hello

Comment: check `appendChild`, it does not return parent node.

Comment: Because [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) returns the element appended and not the parent, ie your first code `AddText` is your text node and not your `li`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`appendChild` returns the appended node:

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
const parent = document.createElement('div');
const result = parent.appendChild(div);
console.log(result === div);
```

So when you do

```
var AddText=document.createElement('li').appendChild(document.createTextNode("hello"));
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The value put into `addText` is the created text node. In contrast, with

```
var  AddText = document.createElement('li');
```

it's the `<li>`, not the text node.

So, with the first approach, the created `<li>` doesn't get used (and probably isn't what you want).

If you wanted to use the `<li>`, and slim your code down, assign to the `.textContent` of the `<li>` instead.

```
Add.addEventListener('click', function(){
    ListParent.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
      .textContent = element.value;
})
```